# MySQL polygon search procedure

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am in MySQL 5.7 I have been trying to get to the bottom of a procedure that isn't working for me, and I'm finding that I'm getting null values which shouldn't be null. The procedure is for finding which area described by a polygon table called csatest1 a point falls within, points are within a table called gsatest1. I just need to find the first csatest1 polygon than encloses a point which is a user input.

Instructions to create and test a test data set that matches mine:

```
    create table gsatest1 (element_id integer, y double, xpanel1 double, xpanel2 double, xpanel3 double, xpanel4 double);
    Insert into gsatest1 (element_id, y, xpanel1,xpanel2,xpanel3,xpanel4)values(11,-4, -5,-6,-7,-8);
    Insert into gsatest1 (element_id, y, xpanel1,xpanel2,xpanel3,xpanel4)values(13,-2, -5,-6,-7,-8);
    Insert into gsatest1 (element_id, y, xpanel1,xpanel2,xpanel3,xpanel4)values(14,-15, -5,-6,-7,-8);
    Insert into gsatest1 (element_id, y, xpanel1,xpanel2,xpanel3,xpanel4)values(15,-28, -5,-6,-7,-8);
    Insert into gsatest1 (element_id, y, xpanel1,xpanel2,xpanel3,xpanel4)values(16,-1500, -5,-6,-7,-8);

    Create table csatest1 (area_id integer, Poly polygon,testtext varchar(300));

    set@testpoly1=ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON (( -1000 -1000, -1000 10, 10 10, 10 -1000, -1000 -1000 ))');
    set@testpoly2=ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON (( -1000 -2000, -1000 10, 10 10, 10 -1000, -1000 -2000 ))');
    set@testpoly3=ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON (( -2000 -2000, -2000 20, 20 20, 20 -2000, -2000 -2000 ))');

    INSERT INTO csatest1 SET Poly = @testpoly1, area_id = 1, testtext = ST_astext(@testpoly1);
    INSERT INTO csatest1 SET Poly = @testpoly2, area_id = 2,testtext = ST_astext(@testpoly2);
    INSERT INTO csatest1 SET Poly = @testpoly3, area_id = 3,testtext = ST_astext(@testpoly3);

    #test that table of polygons csatest1 is working as planned
    Set @ele_no = 2;

    Set @poly = (select poly from csatest1 where area_id=@ele_no);

    set @texttest = (select testtext from csatest1 where area_id = @ele_no);

    Select @ele_no,@poly,@texttest;
```

My Procedure, which runs without errors but returns null values is below. It returns the point value as text without a problem, but the polygon value as coming through as null for some reason I can't figure out.

```
   CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `polygon_matcher`(IN gsa_ele_id integer, IN panel_no integer)
    BEGIN
    Declare done boolean default 0; 
    Declare xval double; 
    Declare yval double;
    declare i integer default 1;
    declare text1 varchar(300);
    declare gsa_pointxy point;
    Declare textgsa_pointxy varchar(300);
    declare csaele_no integer;
    declare poly polygon;
    declare textcsa_polygon varchar(500);
    declare ysno integer default 0;

    #declare the cursor, cursor goes through row by row the table with polygons
    Declare rows cursor for Select area_id from csatest1;
    #declare continue handler
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '02000' SET done=1;

    # create a  table for results 
    CREATE table datadump  (CSA_element_ID integer, textcheck_point varchar (300) , textcheck_polygon varchar (300) , container double);

    #find y value only depends on gsa element ID
     Set yval = (select y from gsatest1 where element_id=gsa_ele_id order by element_id limit 1);

    # extract x value for particular panel number specified by user
     set xval=(
       SELECT
         CASE panel_no
            WHEN 1 THEN xpanel1
            WHEN 2 THEN xpanel2
            WHEN 3 THEN xpanel3
            WHEN 4 THEN xpanel4

        ELSE NULL
      END

     FROM
        gsatest1 order by element_id asc limit 1);

      # make gsa data into a point
      set text1 = concat('POINT (',xval,' ',yval,')');
      set gsa_pointxy = ST_geomfromtext(text1);
      #convert to text for testing
      set textgsa_pointxy = ST_astext(gsa_pointxy);


      #OPEN THE CURSOR
      OPEN rows;
      # tell it to loop through all rows
      repeat

      #get element number from polygons table into cursor
      FETCH rows into csaele_no;
      set poly = (select poly from csatest1 where area_id=csaele_no  order by area_id asc limit 1);
      set textcsa_polygon = ST_astext(poly);

       # return 1 or zero depending on if statment is true
       set ysno = (Select MBRContains(poly , gsa_pointxy));

       # put data into results table
       Insert into datadump (CSA_element_ID, textcheck_point, textcheck_polygon, container) Values (csaele_no, textgsa_pointxy, textcsa_polygon, ysno);

        UNTIL done END REPEAT;
        #close the cursor
        CLOSE rows;

    END
```

Then I called this procedure as follows:
       call polygon_matcher (14,2);

The result:

```
+----------------+-----------------+-------------------+-----------+
| CSA_element_ID | textcheck_point | textcheck_polygon | container |
+----------------+-----------------+-------------------+-----------+
|              1 | POINT(-6 -15)   | NULL              | NULL      |
|              2 | POINT(-6 -15)   | NULL              | NULL      |
|              3 | POINT(-6 -15)   | NULL              | NULL      |
|              3 | POINT(-6 -15)   | NULL              | NULL      |
+----------------+-----------------+-------------------+-----------+
```

Comment: Is this a bug perhaps?  bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=80697

Comment: Never use a variable that has the same name as a column. In your case: "poly".

Comment: Also: can you elaborate what you are trying to calculate (e.g. the expected outcome)? It looks like you calculate MBRContains for all rows, using a cursor to go through all rows. My guess would be that you could replace your whole procedure by one insert (something like `insert into... select ..., mbrcontains(table.poly, <get_the_point>) from table`)

Comment: Not sure what you mean, I did try to do a select function see my other post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60265289/mysql-geometry-function-points-and-polygons) and it wasn't doing what I wanted as the MRBcontains function is only capable of returning a 1 or 0. So if the MRBcontains function was a more flexible function, yes I wouldn't need a procedure.

Comment: And I added a bit more the post to make it clearer, thanks so much for trying to help out.

Comment: But yes @solarflare not calling the variable and column name the same thing fixed it! I'm not a proper programmer (yet) engineer using stuff to make my job easier. Thank you so much, please feel free to add that as your answer if you like.

Comment: Feel free to self-answer. About your comment that you need a procedure: I do not think you do, but if a procedure works for you and if you like it, it's fine, and you can replace it later at any time anyway when you get more comfortable with sql (or if you provide the expected result/explanation, I do not want to dig into your code to check if my assumption is correct, was just my first impression). One last note though: "rows" becomes a keyword in MySQL 8, so you should probably not use it as a variable name (as it will break your procedure when you upgrade).